# Javascript: Assign a function to every HTML element

Tags: javascript

So i wan't to make a function that changes an elements style property.

And I wan't call it like this:
`element.setStyle("display","none");`
I can do it like this:

```
function setStyle(elemnt,attr,val) {
    elemnt.style[attr] =val;
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, there is, but it is not recommended to use.

Comment: MonkeyPatching is bad

Comment: Yes there is. First you try, then we help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can** do this, on modern browsers, by creating a function on `HTMLElement.prototype`:

```js
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "setStyle", {
  value: function(name, value) {
    this.style[name] = value;
  }
});

document.getElementById("foo").setStyle("color", "green");
```

```html
<div id="foo">Hi there</div>
```

Note the use of `Object.defineProperty`; just assigning (`HTMLElement.prototype.setStyle = function...`) would create an *enumerable* property on the prototype, which is usually not a good idea.

***But*** if you do this at all, do it in only your own app/page code, not (for instance) in library code. Whenever your code is going to be combined with other code in situations out of your control, avoid extending built-ins. It's asking for conflicts with other code.

**And** beware that even if you're not combining this with any other code, new methods are added to the DOM periodically. For instance, if you'd added a method called `closest` 4-5 years ago, you'd now be dealing with the fact that a method called `closest` has been added to the Element interface.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```js
function setStyle(el, key, value) {
   el.style[key] = value;
}

setStyle(document.getElementById("test"), "color", "red");
```

```html
<div id="test">test</div>
```